# looping over dynamic string in java

Tags: java

i am stuck in simple loop.. i want a generic way to loop over this string in java

```
{FetchSORDetailsResult=[{SORResData=[{CaseCount=2, MiddleName=M,    SexOffenderIdNumber=429505, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=NY, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/NY/11152.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=11152.JPG, IsAlias=0, LastName=LEVINE}, {CaseCount=1, MiddleName=MARK, SexOffenderIdNumber=179737, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=FL, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/FL/89346.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=89346.JPG, IsAlias=0, LastName=LEVINE}, {CaseCount=2, MiddleName=, SexOffenderIdNumber=429505, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=NY, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/NY/11152.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=11152.JPG, IsAlias=1, LastName=LEVINE}]}]}
```

i have tried stringutils.substringBetween, but it gets me only 1st set of data.

i want to fetch all the data like SexOffenderIdNumber, DOB, firstname, lastname from the string. the string can return multiple data.

any help apprciated

Comment: what exactly do you mean *loop over* the string? do you want to work on each `char` of the String or each word? If it is each char you want, you may want to try something like this: `String myString;     for(char c : myString.toCharArray()){ //work with the char c  }`

Comment: Your string looks like wrongly formatted JSON. To make it valid JSON you would need to replace `=` with `:` and put all strings in quotes (including keys).

Comment: i want to fetch all the data like SexOffenderIdNumber, DOB, firstname, lastname from the string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get that using regular expressions:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String data = "{FetchSORDetailsResult=[{SORResData=[{CaseCount=2, MiddleName=M,    SexOffenderIdNumber=429505, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=NY, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/NY/11152.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=11152.JPG, IsAlias=0, LastName=LEVINE}, {CaseCount=1, MiddleName=MARK, SexOffenderIdNumber=179737, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=FL, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/FL/89346.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=89346.JPG, IsAlias=0, LastName=LEVINE}, {CaseCount=2, MiddleName=, SexOffenderIdNumber=429505, DOB=19760619, SexOffenderDatabaseId=NY, Suffix=, Image=http://secure.hallpassid.com/SORPhotos/NY/11152.JPG, FirstName=STEVEN, PhotoIdentifier=11152.JPG, IsAlias=1, LastName=LEVINE}]}]}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[.[^\\{}]]+\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(matcher.find()){
             matches.add(data.substring(matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end() - 1));       // +1-1 to cut off {}
        }
        for(String line : matches){
            for(String fragment : line.split(","))
                System.out.println(fragment.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Also if `stringutils.substringBetween` works at least once, you can use it in loop, on substring, from point where last match ended, to end of line, and so on.